# What is the equivalent of Proc Sql (in Sas) "Calculated" command in SQL?

Tags: sql, sas

The syntax "Calculated" in Proc SQL allows you to use the alias of a variable that was created in the previous steps.

For example:

```
Select *
id,
sum(amount) as sum
from dataset
group by id
order by calculated sum;
```

Is there an equivalent syntax in SQL that would allow the same result?

Thanks!

Comment: `SQL` is not useful here; you need to define what variant of SQL you are looking for help with.  MS' SQL Server?  Oracle?  SAS' `PROC SQL` is a SQL variant itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use column aliases in the `order by` clause (at least in most databases).  So you can do:

```
Select id, sum(amount) as thesum
from dataset
group by id
order by thesum;
```

(Note that `sum` might a reserved word in some databases, so I'm using another alias.)

Your bigger issue is the "remerging" that SAS does because you have included non-aggregated columns.  In most databases, you would write:

```
Select d.*, sum(d.amount) over (partition by id) as thesum
from dataset d
group by id
order by thesum;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. So other than order by, could I use the alias directly? (For example, in 'group by' or 'where' statement?) I'm mostly using mySQL.

Comment: @skydv . . . hey work in the 'group by', `having`, and `order by` clauses, as documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html.

Answer (score 2):

If your question regards ANSI SQL, the answer is:

There is no such thing like "calculated".

So you would have to calculate the column you want to use and then use it in a second SQL statement.
The approach in SAS SQL is just a convenient shortcut, which is not ANSI SQL conform.

Answer (score 0):

Calculated is a SAS "*[enhancement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vxq9yj2pVWk)*"

You can use a number to reference items in the order that they appear in the select statement.

```
Select
id,
sum(amount) as sum
from dataset
group by 1
order by 2;
```