# Hadoop SQL - Impala and a calculated field

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

I am very new to Hadoop and attempting to use a "calculated" field as one would in SQL:

```
SELECT "one" as test, 
    CASE WHEN calculated test = "one" then "This works"
    else "Nope" 
    end as checker
```

But it appears this generates an error:

> AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1: ...est, CASE WHEN
>   calculated test = "one" then "This work... ^ Encountered: IDENTIFIER
>   Expected: AND, BETWEEN, DIV, ILIKE, IN, IREGEXP, IS, LIKE, NOT, OR,
>   REGEXP, RLIKE, THEN CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Is it not possible to use a "calculated" field in Hadoop? If so, what am I doing wrong? Apologies if I am missing something obvious, again, new to Hadoop.

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: I appreciate that, but unfortunately that had no effect. Please note that I'm trying to use a calculated field, the word "calculated" is what is causing the issue, otherwise it runs fine.

Comment: . . `calculated` is something I know from the SAS proc sql environment.  I don't recall seeing it in any other database.

Answer (score 1):

It is not.  `calculated` is not a reserve word for Impala SQL.

You should probably use `if` or `case` instead.

Here are some examples, from the article [Impala Conditional Functions: IF, CASE, COALESCE, DECODE, NVL, ZEROIFNULL](http://dwgeek.com/impala-conditional-functions-case-coalesce-decode-nvl-zeroifnull.html/):

> ```
> select if(1=1,'TRUE','FALSE') as IF_TEST;
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> select case x when 1 then 'one'
>  when 2 then 'two' 
>  when 0 then 'zero' 
>  else 'out of range' 
>  end
>  from t1;
> ```

**References:**

- [Impala Reserved Words](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_reserved_words.html)
- [Impala Conditional Functions](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_conditional_functions.html)

Comment: Thank you, but the point would be to create the value and then reference it in the same statement. 
      SELECT 'one' as test, 
         if(test = 'one', 'TRUE', 'FALSE') as checker 
... But the variable "test" won't be found in this case.

Comment: I doubt it.  Impala only supports a subset of SQL and primarily for Hive compatability since that's the primary use case.  Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873380/what-is-the-equivalent-of-proc-sql-in-sas-calculated-command-in-sql.  That might help.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out my question was based more on my lack of understanding of SQL then of Hadoop. Having explored it more this week, nesting select statements worked perfectly for what I was attempting to do.

Answer (score 1):

The below query may work the way you want in hive/impala

```
select 
    case when test="one" then "this works"
    else "nope" end as checker 
    from 
    (select "one" as test) a;
```

Comment: Happy to report that works exactly as I was hoping. I can only go one level with it, but cutting the code in half is a big help.